# composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app - bash: composer: command not found

Tags: php, laravel, git, composer-php

I try to install Laravel but got this error "bash: composer: command not found". What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: you should install the composer first.
download from here https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to download composer if you haven't done that yet from https://getcomposer.org/download/ and than you will need to make sure that composer was add to the global path and it should be ok.

Comment: @KristinAve If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted